# Is it possible to send a javascript variable to the create method of a controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I work with Rails 4.

I have a User model and a Record model and I want to send to the create method of the controller two javascript variables.

To do this I implemented an AJAX call :

```
var funds = $('input#test').val();

var weight = $('input#result').val();

$.ajax({
  url: "/final",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
       funds: funds,
       weight: weight,
  },
  complete: function(){
       console.log('Congrats');
  }

});
```

I implemented the route writing this in my config route file :

```
post '/register' => 'users#create'
```

This is my controller :

```js
    def create
        @user = User.new(ticket_params)

        @funds = params([:funds])
        @weight = params([:weight])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }

            Record.create(fund: @funds, weight: @weight)

          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
          format.js
        end
      end
```

But I receive an error 400 bad request.

I would like both the variables `funds`and `weight`to be available in the create method of the controller so that I can use them.

I read that the error 400 bad request shows that I am not using the right verb for my AJAX call. In fact instead of POST using GET makes the error to disappear. But then when I create the User the controller says that my parameters are empty.....But there are not ! I checked it.

**How can I send some javascript variables to the create method ?**

Here is the error message from the network console of my browser :

```js
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: user


Application Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:109:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40:in `create'
```

The error in my console is :

```js
POST http://localhost:3000/final 400 (Bad Request)
m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1:6
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1:6
(anonymous function) @ VM2175:27
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1:5
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1:5
```

Comment: I guess you didnt require the jquery rails js file

Comment: what do you mean ? In the application.js file I require jquery, jquery_ujs

Comment: use this gem properly https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails you your post requests will work

Comment: I already have this gem thus I work with Rails 4

Comment: Is anything coming through in your server log?  You're not really sending javascript variables through here, you're just putting some params in the request.  I would look in the network tab in Chrome Inspector to see what request is being made and then make sure that you have a route matching that url and method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

Actually I was working on the `_form.html.erb`file of my User model. I mean that the webpage I was working on, was the webpage on which the user is filling in a form. What I wanted to do with my AJAX call was to send some parameters to the create method of my controller so that I could then work with these parameters within the create method.

However when doing an AJAX call it triggers the run of the method with all the code in it. And in my controller you can see that the first line of code retrieves the `ticket_params`which are supposed to be the informations that the user filled in  the form. But there were empty thus the user has not yet clicked on the submit button (he has just wrote something in an input of the form that triggers an AJAX call).

So what I did instead of doing an AJAX call to send my parameters to the create action was to declare two more attributes for the **User** model and two use two more **hidden_field** to save each **javascript variable** `weight` and `funds` and when the user click on the submit button my parameters are naturally sent to the create method where I can retrieve them with the line of code `@user = User.new(ticket_params)`.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that you have:

- `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your `Gemfile`
- `//= require jquery` in your  `application.js`

second your `data` has a `,` that should be removed:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/register",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
       authenticity_token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
       funds: funds,
       weight: weight
  },
  complete: function(){
       console.log('Congrats');
  }

});
```

you can place as many parameters as necessary in the ajax `data` parameter.

Let us know if you need more help

Comment: I have the gem jquery-rails. I require jquery in my application.js file I remove the `,` but I still have the error 400 bad request.

Comment: you might want to use the ajax `datatype` parameter (just in case).  And as you will probably have a problem with the csrt token, you should also add the parameter `authenticity_token`. I have updated the code with these.

Comment: What is the web server you are using? is this `WEBrick` (the standard rails one)?

Comment: Yes I use Webrick the standard web server that runs when typing `rails s` into my terminal

Comment: do you mind adding your controller functions `user_params` and `create` to the body of your question? the Ajax call is correct now, so the problem must be in your functions...

Comment: I found the error. When I have time I will post why it was not working. Thanks for your help though